# Is GoLang safe to use partial cache restoration with CircleCI?

Tags: go, circleci, circleci-2.0

Is GoLang Safe to Use **Partial** Cache Restoration with CircleCI?

The CircleCI official documentation (https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/) shows that these languages are safe (some with conditions), but I was not able to find GoLang in the doc, tried googling but nothing much. None of the examples I found are using partial cache restoration.  So I ended up here asking if it is safe.  Can anyone help?

```
Safe to use partial cache restoration?

Bundler(Ruby)      Yes (with caution)
Gradle(Java)       Yes
Maven(Java)        Yes
Leiningen(Clojure) Yes
npm(Node)          Yes (with NPM5+)
pip(Python)        Yes (with pipenv)
Yarn(Node)         Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

In their [golang example](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-go/), they are using cache restoration.

Comment: yes they are, what I was wondering was if `partial cache restoration` is safe or not

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is Yes

see [this post](https://hackernoon.com/continuous-integration-circleci-vs-travis-ci-vs-jenkins-41a1c2bd95f5) for your information?

Comment: I checked the post but it does not say anything about partial cache restoration.  Would you explain more about why you think the answer is yes?